# Cubase stops recording when Sibelius reaches the end of the score

Tags: recording

If I have a score open in Sibelius at the same time I'm recording MIDI in Cubase (AI Elements 8), the play position in Sibelius moves to the score time corresponding to the time in Cubase, and when it reaches the end of the score, Cubase stops recording.  I'm sure that this is useful for somebody, but I'd prefer that Cubase and Sibelius not communicate with each other.  How do I change the configuration to prevent this?

Comment: Does it keep playing, just stop recording? What happens if you tap O to disable the dropout point? I've never run the two in tandem, so idk how the punch-out message is transmitted.

Comment: It stops completely (both playing and recording).  It can be started again (manually), but when I'm recording a click-track, I need continuity, else I have to start over.  As for tapping O, I'm not understanding the question.  O is for "Audio Punch Out," right?  I'm not using audio (I'm recording a MIDI click-track).  I've never used Audio Punch Out ... is that something that would affect how Cubase and Sibelius communicate?  I just want to have them run completely independently; how do I sever the real-time connection between them?

Comment: idk, sorry - it's probably sending something like MTC over the inter-application bus, if it doesn't use Rewire, but I'm guessing you're probably on Windows, which I haven't a clue about in DAW terms. On the Mac, you can set IAC to not send MTC. The punch in/out operates on all record types.

Comment: Thanks, Tetsujin, you're helping me get on the right track.  I'm on a Mac, but I can't figure out how to set IAC to not send MTC.  Here's what the IAC Driver Properties looks like: http://www.musanim.com/img/IACDriverConfiguration.jpg  Is this the wrong place to change the IAC/MTC setting?

Comment: tbh, it's so long since I used it I'm struggling to remember. You should be able to see each device in the main page & drag lines between them. I can't remember if apps appear in there too. If not, then that's a red herring, sorry. You'd have to figure how the 2 are communicating. Rewire used to be the common method. I haven't used Sibelius in probably 20 years, long before you could do this type of link-up.

Comment: Right --- it's a new problem.  Well, thanks for your help.